# имитация нажатия клавиатуры с++

Tags: c++

Пробовал 2 метода имитации нажатия клавиатуры в hwnd. Ни один из не работает. На формах полазил,тоже ничего не получается.
PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_A, 0) - Тоже не работает
Код:

```
HWND handle = FindWindow(L"Notepad",NULL);
    if (handle) {
        cout << handle;
        SendMessage(handle, WM_SETFOCUS, VK_Q, 0);

    }
    else {
        cout << "None" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем `WM_SETFOCUS` передавать код клавиши? Этот параметр для извещения о том, от какого окна перешёл фокус.

А с нажатием - нужно передать и нажатие, и отжатие (`WM_KEYUP`). И использовать метод посылки, задействующий очередь сообщений - `PostMessage(...);`.

Кроме того, есть `SendInput(...);` и устаревший `keybd_event(...);`

Answer (score 0):

В текущее окно:

```
keybd_event('C', 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event('C', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

В любое определенное по `HWND`:

```
HWND wndHndl = FindWindow(_T("ApplicationName"), NULL);
PostMessage(wndHndl, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_C, 0);
```

Comment: Я уже находил такое решение,но оно не работает

Comment: @OlegTsvetkov что значит не работает?

Comment: я пытаюсь вписать в блокнот какой либо символу(учусь так сказать плюсам) hwnd находит, но символ в блокноте не появляется. И пример с калькулятором брал, та же фигня. Ну или я дурак,который для данной цели вообще не в том направлении пошёл

Comment: у меня все работает, мне кажется, вы не находите `HWND`, если его вывести чему он равен?

Comment: у меня вот так hwnd:00080A2A